# On topic: product feature question?

Tags: discussion, scope

Regarding:

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/14402

Is this question a good question for SA?  I don't know whether to vote to close or not.

It is dangerously near the line of being a shopping recommendation question.  The OP knows the feature they want, and why they want it.

On the other hand, it is not clear whether it exists in the market--and if it does, which regional market(s).

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct is that we should take things like that, because they're a variant of "what should I look for" questions. It's good to know whether a feature is something that potentially exists before you make it a desired/required feature.